# create iOS software without iOS Hardware

Tags: delphi

can I create Freeware software for iOS  (MAC / IPAD) with Delphi XE2 or DELPHI XE3 without having access to any iOS Hardware? 
Have seen the process for rich guys with iOS HW according to :

http://blogs.embarcadero.com/ao/2011/10/26/39188

In my case I just want to release my freeware programms also for iOS  using DELPHI and FIREMONKEY.

Comment: "without having access to any iOS Hardware?"
Compiler must to have access to the OS because depended libraries. To correct link binary code. So if you won't to have in your code monsters such as Java, Python or any else - install target OS in your comp (using VirtualBox for example) and compile project on it.

Comment: Technically you could run MacOSX on a Virtual Machine and run XCode there. The legality of this is questionable even if you do have a MacOSX license...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS development was disabled in XE3 because the new FireMonkey 2.0 framework is not ready for iOS yet.  iOS support will be re-enabled in a future release.  XE3 only supports Windows and Mac OSX development.

XE2 supports iOS development, just with the older FireMonkey 1.0 framework.  You can set the iOS simulator as a Target platform for a Delphi project.

However, in any configuration, you need to have a Mac with the XCode compiler installed in order to actually produce Mac/iOS executables.  The Delphi compiler currently compiles code into an intermediate format that XCode then consumes.  Embarcadero will release a new Delphi compiler that produces Mac/iOS executables directly in a later release.

If you cannot wait that long, then use FreePascal/Lazarus instead.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau "Free Pascal (aka FPK Pascal) is a 32 and 64 bit professional Pascal compiler. It can target multiple processor architectures: Intel x86, AMD64/x86-64, PowerPC, PowerPC64, SPARC, and ARM. Supported operating systems include Linux, FreeBSD, Haiku, Mac OS X/iOS/Darwin, DOS, Win32, Win64, WinCE, OS/2, MorphOS, Nintendo GBA, Nintendo DS, and Nintendo Wii. Additionally, JVM, MIPS (big and little endian variants) and Motorola 68k architecture targets are available in the development versions."

Comment: will XE2 iOS/OSX support start with release of Mobile studio in next XE3 update?

Comment: @user1769184: I am not at liberty to answer that question at this time.